# Point after the button with icon after material update to 15?

Tags: css, angular-material, material-design, iconbutton

After material update to 15 i see this point after the button with icon?

```
<td *matCellDef="let element" class="col-options" mat-cell>
  <button
    [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"
    mat-icon-button
  >
    <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
    <app-mat-menu-item
      icon="delete_forever"
      [classes]="['text-warn']"
      [iconClasses]="['text-warn']"
      (buttonClicked)="deleteDocument(element)"
    ></app-mat-menu-item>
  </mat-menu>
</td>
```

Delete 'mat-icon-button' class, it is not visible any more...

It is not an element after this cell.
Have no idea where it comes from...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it was tricky to find

```
.col-options {
  min-width: 64px;
  max-width: 64px;
}
```

somehow this created this strange point.

Removing this class solved the issue.